# How can I calculate a column with the last value of another table in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I have a table that comes with duplicated "Contract" number and some reasons of denying an offer like this:

| Contract | Reason |
| --- | --- |
| A | Rsn1 |
| B | Rns2 |
| A | Rsn3 |

And I want a new table like:

| Contract(Distinct) | Reason |
| --- | --- |
| A | Rsn3 |
| B | Rns2 |

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In the Query Editor (Transform)

- Group by Contract
- Aggregate with the last entry in each grouped subtable

```
let

//Change next two lines to reflect actual data source
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WclTSUQoqzjNUitWJVnICcfKKjcAcqIyxUmwsAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Contract = _t, Reason = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Contract", type text}, {"Reason", type text}}),
    
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Contract"}, {
        {"Reason", each List.Last([Reason]), type nullable text}
    })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```